# iphone error dialog?

Tags: iphone, error-handling

I wonder if is possible display a dialgo when a unexpected error happend in the iPhone (and not quit blindy the app!) and have time to log or send by email the crash...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. For starts implement NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler) and then use something like [Crash Reporter](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/iphone/Crash_Reporter.20090129.html). Good stuff.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you can show a dialog, but you can probably do some logging by specifying a top-level exception handler using the function `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler`

Answer (score 1):

I remember there being a method you could override in your application delegate class that would be called in the event of an unhandled exception. A few days ago someone wrote a blog post where they shipped off the exception information to a web service from that method.

I apologize that I can neither find the name of the method in the UIApplicationDelegate protocol or the blog post I saw the other day. Apple's online documentation seems to be un-searchable at the moment (grrr!) and I cannot remember where I saw that blog post - if I find it, I'll edit this post to include a link to it.

But it **may** be possible to have some sort of recovery, or at least the ability to store off error information to disk so it can be sent later.